# How to log out from skype app?

Tags: windows-8, login, skype, modern-ui

I have installed the Skype-App for Windows 8 and a friend logged in first with **his account**.
Now I want to log him out to log in myself with **my account** but there is no **Logout** option.
I tried to uninstall and then re-install the app but then my friend is *still* logged in with **his account**.

How can I log out from the Skype-App for Windows 8?

Comment: Your friend logged into your account?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: In the future, you should create a separate account for your friend.

Comment: @Ramhound: He's asking how to re-log-in as the correct Skype user.

Comment: my question is: how can i log out at the skype app

Comment: There should be an option to switch which account you log into.

Comment: @Ramhound: There isn't

Comment: can`t yu unistall Skype and install it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While using Skype press Win+C (charms bar) then click Settings and in app Options you will be able to logout.

[image]

Comment: I got the newest version of Skype app, but no such option?

Comment: It only shows up if you are already logged in, otherwise you won't see it. BTW: I'm using the latest version too.

Comment: with my version of skype it also works (i dunno which version i have -.-)

Comment: Will this also unlink Microsoft and Skype accounts that have been linked, or just allow you to log in with another acc?

Comment: @Matsemann: It only allows to log out from the currently logged in account, which is the correct and specific answer to my question

Comment: This only works if you are logged with a local windows account.

Answer (score 12):

The Skype account has been linked with your Microsoft Account. At the time, there is no way to remove this link.

Found this on Skype forum:
[Unlinking Microsoft Account](http://community.skype.com/t5/General-Discussion/Unlinking-Microsoft-Account/td-p/1045738)

> Please [contact Skype customer service](https://support.skype.com/faq/FA1170?intcmp=SN-Mods) as they can help you unmerging
>   Microsoft accounts that were merged with a Skype account incorrectly.

Comment: I think your answer belongs to this question: http://superuser.com/q/557991/153816

Answer (score 6):

The page [Why is Skype for Windows 8 always on?](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-8/Why-is-Skype-for-Windows-8-always-on/m-p/1154364) explains that you can't, because this way, Skype can be used as a phone.

> The best way to answer those questions is with a metaphor. Imagine you had a mobile phone but every time someone wanted to call or text message you they had to find a way to tell you to turn on your phone. It wouldn’t be very useful, if they had a way to tell you to turn your phone on, they wouldn’t need to call you.

Comment: This is a joke feature and terrible explanation. I'm the one who decide whether people should call me or not, or either I want to Log out or not. Even with my mobile I'm disabling it (airplane mode) when I'm busy at work or before going to sleep, but the different with phone is that it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Only way I've found to effectively "sign out" is to kill the application. Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open the administrative context menu, choose Task Manager, then locate Skype in the list of processes and end it.

You can't sign out of Skype without signing in as someone else so once Skype has started you have to kill the application or reboot the machine. vhanla's gif shows you go to options to sign out but that "option" is now under profile. Seems the Skype metro app has a ways to go.

Comment: this one worked for me :D