# How to merge Microsoft account with skype account

Tags: windows-8, skype

I accidentally used the "Log in with Microsoft account"-function in the skype app for windows 8. Now I don´t know how to merge my real skype account with the microsoft account?
I use two different e-Mails.

Comment: There is already a discussion on the public skype forum, look here: [Skype Forum](http://community.skype.com/t5/General-Discussion/Unlinking-Microsoft-Account/td-p/1045738)